# Jquery push object variable

Tags: jquery, push

```
   var obj = [];
  $("tr[class*='row_']").each(function () {
   var coord = ($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().match(/\d{1,3}\|\d{1,3}/g)).toString();


    //alert($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text())

   if (obj[coord]) {obj[coord]++;}
   else { obj.push({coord : 1 }) }

   })

    alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

My output:

```
     [{"coord":1},{"coord":1},{"coord":1},{"coord":1},{"coord":1},{"coord":1}]
```

When it should be:

```
 523|546 : 3,
 521|424 : 3
```

How wan I push "name" : 1 when coord is my name?

Comment: where are those numbers coming from? can you post us the table?

Comment: The table looks like this : 005 (523|426) C45 x 3 and [166 Flora] (521|424) C45 x 3. My regex is correct since I already tested that, the problem is pushing a coordinate (523|426 for example) with the number 1 in an object. (So if the coordinate isnt in the object yet, push coord : 1, else 1 + 1 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an array in your code `var obj = []`. If you want an object you need to do this `var obj = {}`.

Then later on you use `obj.push({coord : 1 })`. That only works for arrays. For objects you can just do this `obj[coord] = 1`

```
var obj = {};
$("tr[class*='row_']").each(function () {
    var coord = ($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().match(/\d{1,3}\|\d{1,3}/g)).toString();
    //alert($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text())

    if (obj[coord]) {
       obj[coord]++;
    }  
    else { 
      obj[coord] = 1; 
    }
});

alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: That doensn't work, the object is empty at the start, so you can't just do that because you have to add the key (coord) and the initial value (1) first.

Comment: Let me add a simple jsFiddle. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Never mind, that was a stupid mistake of mine, lol. Thank you for your answer, accepted it :)

Comment: I mean I'll accept in three minutes, can't right now. :)

Comment: Yeah no problem. Since I already completed the jsFiddle. Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/daGEJ/

Comment: Fantastic! Is just what I'm looking for!